# programmatically triggering a scroll or a keypress event in jsdom window

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom, jsdom

I am trying to trigger a `scroll` event or a `keypress` event on a window that I have loaded under `jsdom`. I have loaded the window using `jsdom.jsdom()` function, and it has the external resources loaded (i.e.. the scripts on the page itself). Basically I am trying to trigger these events so that the javascript on the page can listen to those events and loads the next page of data, as the page has the autoload feature when the scrolled to bottom. But I am having trouble with just triggering the `scroll` event, let alone triggering `scroll` to the bottom of the page. It is just getting stuck, nothing is happening.

I also tried to trigger `keypress` event with the key of `end` but for that I am not even able to set a handler for keypress. again getting stuck.

I am using `jsdom.jqueryify()` on the window to embed `jquery` code in it. I thought
with that I could use jquery function like .scroll() to set a test handler, but again it is getting stuck, without giving any error messages.
Here is the code:

```
var document = jsdom.jsdom(str, null, {});
var window = document.parentWindow;

jsdom.jQueryify(window, "jquery.js", function () {
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        console.log("Scroll Happened.");
    });
    console.log("Triggering Scroll event...");  // 1
    $(window).trigger('scroll');
    console.log("Scroll event triggered.");     // 2
}
```

This code does not even reach 1st position, however if I change `$(window)` to `window` it crosses 1st position but still doesn't reach 2nd position.

I also tried:

```
window.dispatchEvent('scroll');
window.scrollByLines(1);
```

instead of:

```
window.trigger('scroll');
```

but no change. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is pretty simple: `$` is not defined in the context in which your code executes. The fix is to add to your callback the parameters `window` and `$`. They are initialized by `jQueryify` as you'd expect. The following outputs to the console everything you wanted:

```
var jsdom = require("jsdom");

var document = jsdom.jsdom();
var window = document.parentWindow;

jsdom.jQueryify(window, "jquery-1.10.2.js", function (window, $) {
    try {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            console.log("Scroll Happened.");
        });
        console.log("Triggering Scroll event...");  // 1
        $(window).trigger('scroll');
        console.log("Scroll event triggered.");     // 2
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }
});
```

I've added the `try ... catch` for illustration purposes. If you remove `window, $` from the parameters, you can see that the `try ... catch` catches a `ReferenceError` because `$` is not defined.

The lesson here is that jsdom effectively creates a new JavaScript virtual machine in which it executes the scripts loaded by the window. So symbols that are defined in this virtual machine are not *necessarily* defined outside of it. And symbols of the same name that are defined inside the jsdom virtual machine *and* outside of it do not generally point to the same *object*. (For instance, `console` outside the virtual machine created by jsdom and `console` inside of it are not the same object.)

Comment: Thanks @Louis that cleared a lot. Although i have decided to use phantomjs for all my data collection needs. jsdom seems to have other limitations, but is good for light browser simulation. Thanks again.